# how can i update database on browser window close?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-7

I am trying to stream some videos to users and i want to enable them to resume watching a video when they leave the website and enter again.
As far as i know storing the video time in browser's local storage and retrieving it when they come back is the best way, but in this case, when the user logins from different PC or browser the video watched time resets.
As synchronous Ajax is disabled in some browsers now, I also can't save the watched time in database on browser close (using `onunload` or `beforeunload` events).

Another way i have tried is, to save the time when user clicks on pause button like this:

```js
var video1 = document.getElementById('video1');

function videoPausePlayHandler(e) {
    if (e.type == 'pause') {
        //saving the watched time in databse using Ajax
    }
}
video1.addEventListener('pause', videoPausePlayHandler, false);
```

But again when user closes the browser window or anything else rather than clicking on pause button, it won't work.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: From user point of view. Site which make functionalities like this (youtube for example), just periodly save the user avencement in the video. It rollback it a bit on the next connection.

Comment: @JulienMaret how do i save the time? and where? database?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the browser’s `onunload` event and send a `Navigator.sendBeacon` to asynchronously send your timestamp to your server without blocking the user from closing the browser window. [sendBeacon Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon). The Browser coverage looks quite good. Just the old IE does not support it at all.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. however, I'm using Laravel, and need CSRF token header to be sent with the beacon. on the other side as per [W3C](https://w3c.github.io/beacon/) beacons cannot have custom headers. any ideas?

Comment: Ah indeed! In this case you can periodically send the timestamp to your backend while playing. Whenever the user close the browser window you have the latest timestamp

Comment: yes but that puts a high load to DB. I found a solution to pass CSRF token with Beacons, by ```data.append('_token', token);```

Comment: As per documentation sadly this hack is and will get further deprecated in newer browser versions because of security issues